# Puppet making one include depend on another within a class

Tags: puppet, boxen

I'm trying to get boxen set up and want to do something like this:

```
class mycompany::environment {

  include iterm2::stable

  include iterm2::colors::solarized_dark
}
```

And in my `manifests/site.pp`, I `include mycompany::environment`.

But `iterm2::colors::solarized_dark` is just configuration, and if it gets applied before iterm2 is actually installed, we get an error. How can I make that statement depend on the previous one (`include iterm2::stable`)?

I've looked at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html but I didn't understand all of it. Sorry, beginner to puppet here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class["iterm2::stable"] -> Class["iterm2::colors::solarized_dark"]
```

This is one way to do it.

Comment: Simple answer, simple question. Thanks!